# Mysql installation in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I had seen many answers to install MySQL.
I had tried everything.
It shows:
There's no MySQL already installed
Unable to locate package MySQL-server
For synaptic, there's no keyword found
Unable to connect to 172.17.0.1:3128 if I try update. 
Am sick of all the errors. 
Can anyone guide me from the beginning to install MySQL ??
Please asap since it's urgent ! :) Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`

Comment: What **version** of Ubuntu do you have? are you using some kind of proxy?

Comment: `mysql` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download all the packages manually and try. this type of installation you dont get 'unable to locate *somePackage*'

- go to this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

(assuming you want to install latest mysql version)

- Then select your platform as "Ubuntu Linux". And download all the
  packages according to Ubuntu version and whether your computer is 64bit or 32bit.
  (dont worry there might be around 11 packages)
- copy all packages to folder temp(for example) in your home directory.
- open terminal. then type `cd temp`
- then type `sudo dpkg -i *`
- by this all packages will be installed and so will the latest stable mysql version.

Comment: The version of MySQL Server at your link is 5.6.21 compared to mysql-server-5.6 from the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 14.04 which is 5.6.19. The more recent version of MySQL Server 5.7.5 at your link is a Development Release, NOT a Generally Available Release. So my question is: What advantage if any does downloading a MySQL .deb file from the link in your answer have over installing a MySQL package from the Ubuntu repos? Is there any reason aside from the more recent version to choose the MySQL Server from that link instead of installing MySQL Server from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: @karel  advantage is, like i said, you dont get any errors like 'unable to locate package'. from the link you can download any version you want(even the old ones or which ever version you like). i dont recommend downloading development release. did i cleared you question ?

Comment: you may suggest this to her in comment under question

Comment: ^^^ Dhivyaa Naraayani might have got the `Unable to locate package MySQL-server` message because `mysql` is case sensitive. I have suggested this to her in a comment under her question.